# flask ['GET'] method always returns <Response streamed [200 OK]> with pytest

Tags: python, flask, pytest

When i use pytest for my flask app and test a GET method through pytest it always returns `<Response streamed [200 OK]>`

Here is the code for the flask app:

```py
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/get_node', methods=['GET'])
def get_node():
    return "tests"
```

Here is the code for the pytest code:

```py
import pytest
import flask_app 
import json 

@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def setup_get_node():
    test_client = flask_app.app.test_client()
    yield test_client

def test_get_node(setup_get_node):
    node_to_get = {"node": "value" }
    node_read = setup_get_node.get('/get_node', 
        data=json.dumps(node_to_get), content_type='application/json')
    assert node_read == True
```

The value return from  the get() method on the test client is always: `<Response streamed [200 OK]>`.
The `/get_node/` route works fine in practices when i query it through Postman... but its always wrong with pytest...

Any thoughts?

Comment: according to http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/testing/#the-first-test , maybe you have to access to `data` attribute (e.g. `node_read.data`).

Comment: yes. that was it... should have read the docs closers... feel kinda dumb. however these still worked fine in postman without using the .data value..